# Dialog update and open calls postconstruct

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have command link in primefaces datatable with action to open a dialog. When clicked on link always calls postconstruct.

My requirement is update to dialog with required details for editing.

Partial code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable id="sampleMasterListDataTable" var="sampleEntry"
    value="#{sampleMgmtBean.sampleMasterList}" paginator="true" rows="5"
    paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} 
    {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPage="5" style="width:600px;">   

     <p:column headerText="Invoice No">
         <h:outputText value="#{sampleEntry.invoiceNo}" />
     </p:column>
     <p:column headerText="Sales Date">
         <h:outputText value="#{sampleEntry.date}">
             <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
         </h:outputText>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Update">
        <p:commandButton id="editSalesLink" value="Edit"
          action="#{sampleMgmtBean.pullSalesDetails(sampleEntry)}"
          update=":tabView:editDialog" process="@this" ajax="true"
          oncomplete="editSalesDialog.show();" />
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

**Dialog Code:**

```
  <p:dialog id="editDialog" header="Update Sales Dialog"
      widgetVar="editSalesDialog" resizable="false" height="500" modal="true">
   <h:form id="sampleMasterEditForm" prependId="false">
      <p:panelGrid columns="8" cellpadding="5" style="width: 650px">
          <h:outputLabel for="editInvoiceNo" value="Invoice:" />
          <p:inputText value="#{sampleMgmtBean.sampleMaster.invoiceNo}"
            id="editInvoiceNo" required="false" label="invoiceNo" />
        <h:outputLabel for="editSalesDate" value="Sales Date:" />
        <p:calendar id="editSalesDate" mode="popup" styleClass="calendar"
            navigator="true" readonly="readonly"
            value="#{sampleMgmtBean.sampleMaster.date}" yearRange="1900:2050"
            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
        </p:calendar>
     </p:panelGrid>
   </h:form>
 </p:dialog>
```

**Java code**

```
 @ManagedBean(name="salesMgmtBean") 

 @ViewScoped 

 public class SalesMgmtBean implements Serializable {

      @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    //new objects
  } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your button has an action that causes a new view to be rendered.  this is probably causing your view scoped bean to be re-instantiated as jsf is probably interpreting the result of your action as a "new view" thus causing the old view conversation to get flushed.  since the bean only has view scope, a new one will be instantiated causing the PostContruct interceptor to execute.

rather than calling an action in the button, try chaining two ActionListeners (one after another) or one tied to the control and one as a child of the control (f:actionListener).  that way you don't get a view transition (which is what actions cause).

it would be extra helpful if you added enough meat from the other bean showing what the outcomes for the action method are.